# Angular could not resolve from state

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I used jhipster to generate my app and I tried to add two different types of forms, that would both use same entity (one wouldn't use all fields in entity and other would use all).

Now, it works alright for:

```
    .state('xyz', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/xyz',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'xyzs'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/xyz/xyzs.html',
                controller: 'XyzController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
        }
    }).state('xyz.new', {
        parent: 'xyz',
        url: '/new',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
        },
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/xyz/xyz-dialog.html',
                controller: 'XyzDialogController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                backdrop: 'static',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    entity: function () {
                        return {
                            ...
                        };
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function() {
                $state.go('xyz', null, { reload: true });
            }, function() {
                $state.go('xyz');
            });
        }]
    })
```

And it works alright, but if I change it a small bit and use:

```
    .state('xyz', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/xyz',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'xyzs'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/xyz/xyzs.html',
                controller: 'XyzController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
        }
    }).state('a-xyz.new', {
        parent: 'xyz',
        url: '/a/new',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
        },
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/xyz/a-xyz-dialog.html',
                controller: 'XyzDialogController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                backdrop: 'static',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    entity: function () {
                        return {
                            ...
                        };
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function() {
                $state.go('xyz', null, { reload: true });
            }, function() {
                $state.go('xyz');
            });
        }]
    })
```

And I've change my 
`ui-sref="xyz.new"`
to
`ui-sref="a-xyz.new"`
in my html template

I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'a-xyz.new' from state 'xyz'
transitionTo@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3180:17
go@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3108:14
clickHook/</transition<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4158:9
timeout/timeoutId<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19157:28
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5869:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6145:7
```

Comment: it expects a-xyz to be a state, for which 'a-xyz.new' would be a child state. Try renaming 'xyz' to ''a-xyz'...

Comment: Ok. That works. But doesn't make sense to me. Why would I have to specify a parent, if it doesn't care and wants parents state name to be same as its own state name? Is there any other way to do it? So I could link many other states to one parent? Like `a-xyz`, `b-xyz`? I would have to do a lot of duplicated code (for edit, delete) if it wasn't possible

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation is basically used to indicate child state for a parent state. You may refer to this link for better understanding of nested views/states.

[Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Go through this:

[Why Parent State must exist](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#parent-must-exist)

One parent can have multiple child states. So, if your parent state is 'xyz', you can multiple child states as 'xyz.a', 'xyz.b', 'xyz.c' etc.